# Questions about Hodge conjecture

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, homology-cohomology, complex-geometry

In the [following link](http://garf.ub.es/milenio/img/Presentacion_Hodge.pdf), pages : $133$ and $65$, we find the following paragraph translated from spanish to english :

> Let $M$ be a compact kahler manifold
>
> Let $S \subset M $ be a complex submanifold of ( complex ) dimension $ n-p $
>
> We have : $PD[S] \in H^{2p} ( M , \mathbb{Z} ) \cap H^{p,p} (M) $ :
>
> Indeed :
>
> Obviously : $PD[S] \in H^{Zp} ( M , \mathbb{Z} )$
>
> $H^{2p}(M,\mathbb{C} ) = \displaystyle \bigoplus_{i+j=2p} H^{i,j} (M) $
>
> Let $ \alpha \in H^{q_{1} , q_{2}} (M) $ , $ q_1 + q_2 = 2n-2p $.
>
> $ \alpha \in \sum f_{I,J} dz_{i_{1}} \wedge \dots \wedge dz_{i_{q_{1}}} \wedge d \overline{z}_{j_{1}} \wedge \dots \wedge d\overline{z}_{j_{q_{2}}} $
>
> $ \langle \alpha , PD[S] \rangle = \int_S \alpha $
>
> Locally, $ S = \{ \ z_1 = 0 , \dots , z_p = 0 \ \} $
>
> If $ q_1 > n-p $ then $ dz_{i_{1}} \wedge \dots \wedge dz_{i_{q_{1}}} = 0 $
>
> If $ q_2 > n-p $ then $ d \overline{z}_{j_{1}} \wedge \dots \wedge d \overline{z}_{j_{q_{2}}} = \overline{dz_{j_{1}} \wedge \dots \wedge dz_{j_{q_{2}}}} = 0 $.
>
> If $ (q_1 , q_2) \neq (n-p , n-p)$, then $ \int_S \alpha = 0  $
>
> $ \Longrightarrow PD[S] \in H^{p,p} (M) $

**My questions are** :

$ 1) $ According to page : $65$, if $ \begin{cases} dz_j = dx_j + i dy_j \\ d \overline{z}_j = dx_j - i dy_j \end{cases} $, how do we go from
$ dz_{i_{1}} \wedge \dots \wedge dz_{i_{q_{1}}} \wedge d \overline{z}_{j_{1}} \wedge \dots \wedge d\overline{z}_{j_{q_{2}}} $ and developpe it, to obtain a formula in terms of $ dx_i $ and $ dy_j $ and the symbol :
$ \wedge $ ?

$ 2) $ Why is $ d \overline{z}_{j_{1}} \wedge \dots \wedge d \overline{z}_{j_{q_{2}}} = \overline{dz_{j_{1}} \wedge \dots \wedge dz_{j_{q_{2}}}} $.

$ 3) $ Why does the fact $ \ \ \big( \ \ $ if $ (q_1 , q_2) \neq (n-p , n-p) $, then $ \int_S \alpha = 0 \ \ \big) \ \ $ involve that $ \Longrightarrow \ \ PD[S] \in H^{p,p} (M) $
( explicitly, please ) ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What did you try ? 1)  and 2) follows from definitions. And 3) also follows from definition as well (you need to know the existence of Hodge decomposition of course).

Comment: Yes, that's right Nicolas,thank you.  :-)  but, can you write me a detail answer about these three questions please ?.  :-) Concerning question $ 1) $, i know we need to use the determinant of every minor of a matrix that i don't knom its form, but, i don't know what is the final formula, because it's hard for me to do this tiresome calculus which never ends. Thank you.  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in comments everything follows from definitions.

1) e.g we have  $$dz_1 \wedge d \overline z_2 = (dx_1 + idy_1) \wedge (dx_2 - idy_2) = dx_1 \wedge dx_2 + dy_1 \wedge dy_2 - (dx_1 \wedge dy_2 + dy_1 \wedge dx_2)$$
and you can immediately generalize.

2) This is how you define conjugaison of differential forms.

3) By Hodge decomposition, write $\alpha = \lambda_{0,2p}\alpha^{0,2p} + \dots + \lambda_{2p,0} \alpha^{2p,0} $. Integration against $S$ shows that all the $\lambda$'s are zero excepted $\lambda_{p,p}$, this exactly means that $PD[S] \in H^{p,p}(M)$.

Comment: Thank you Nicolas for your answer, but if we have a long piece $ dz_1 \wedge d  \overline{z}_2 \wedge \dots \wedge d \overline{z}_{m-1} \wedge dz_{m} $ for example, how to obtain the right formula without passing through doing this fastidious developpement that you use above, only using determinant of minors of a matrix for example ?  :-)

Comment: Ok, thank you, in understand now.  :-)